# Getting JSONDecodeError while saving api data to csv

Tags: python, json, csv, python-requests

I am working on a project on which I need to collect the data from two APIs and paste ii in existing excel sheet in sheet 1 and sheet 2.

As step1 I am trying to convert the json api data to csv but getting the following error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

However the URL is working fine in browser.

[Screenshot of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hv1mb.jpg)

```
import csv
import requests

CSV_URL = 'https://dsv-ops-toolkit.ihsmvals.com/ftp?config=tradition&file=Tradition_Basis_RFR_2021_11_26_11_00_00.csv'

with requests.Session() as s:
    download = s.get(CSV_URL)

    decoded_content = download.content.decode('utf-8')

    cr = csv.reader(decoded_content.splitlines(), delimiter=',')
    my_list = list(cr)
    for row in my_list:
        print(row)
```

Also how can I save the data from two API's using the above script? Does it require a `for` loop?

Comment: dont trap the datas from url, difficult to help you without to show datas

Comment: i have added an image, hope it helps

Comment: its not a json, its already a csv file, so its norma lyou have an error when you try to parse a json..

Comment: but when i right click on it and try to save it, it gets saved in text format

Comment: yes its text format but delimited by comma, so its csv file

Comment: is there a way to download it on my system via python ?

Comment: can anyone pls help, how to loop in one more URL in the above code